# How to save the output of for loop to the same column?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

In the for loop, I don't know why when I try to save the output to dataframe

```
Grid <- c("tt6483832/","tt5164196/","tt4052886/","tt1826940/")
BaseURL <- "http://www.imdb.com/title/"


for (i in 1:4){
FullURL <-paste(BaseURL,Grid[i], sep="")
Title <- read_html(FullURL)
title_contents <- html_element(Title,"selector")
storyline <- html_element(Title,"selector")
rating <- html_element(Title,"selector")
title_contents <- html_text(title_contents)
rating <- html_text(rating)
storyline <- html_text(storyline)
print(title_contents)
print(rating)
print(storyline)
df <- cbind(title_contents,rating,storyline)
}

df <- data.frame(df)
```

The output will only have the fourth one which is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XGDm.png)

How can I save all the output of for loop to the same column such as

```
    C1      C2      C3
R1  title1  rating1 storyline1
R2  title2  rating2 storyline2
R3  title3  rating3 storyline3
R4  title4  rating4 storyline4
```

Comment: What is `show_urls`?

Comment: oh sorry I didn't put it on. I've already edited. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are overwriting the previous results thus you are getting result for only last one(fourth).

Create an empty vector `df1` and store the results of each loop in it.

```
Grid <- c("tt6483832/","tt5164196/","tt4052886/","tt1826940/")
BaseURL <- "http://www.imdb.com/title/"

df1 = c()

for (i in 1:4){
  
  FullURL <-paste(BaseURL,Grid[i], sep="")
  
  title_contents <- FullURL %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.dxSWFG') %>% html_text()
  
  rating <- FullURL %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.iTLWoV') %>% html_text()
  rating = rating[1]
  
  storyline <- FullURL %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.eqlIrG') %>% html_text()
  
  df <- cbind(title_contents,rating,storyline)
  
  df1 = rbind(df, df1)
}

df1 <- data.frame(df1)
```